# larger math fonts for R Markdown

Tags: equations, fontsize, r, knitr

I am looking for an "easy", i.e. not package dependent way of increasing the font size of the math equations I embed in my Rmd documents (eventually compiled by knitr).
As an example:

```
$$
\boxed{P(x=a;N,A,n,a) = \frac{{A \choose a} \cdot {N-A \choose n-a} }{{N \choose n}}}
$$
```

yields an equation my html document which is much too small for easy reading.

Thanks!
ml

Comment: How about $$ \LARGE \boxed{P(x=a;N,A,n,a) = \frac{{A \choose a} \cdot {N-A \choose n-a} }{{N \choose n}}} $$